# 5000 Limit to Google Search Console when using 'query' dimension

Tags: google-search-console, google-search-api

Calling the GSC api with the query dimension I am only getting 5,000 rows per day. I saw in the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/how-tos/all-your-data#by-property) that "For greater detail, including query, country, and/or device information, at the expense of losing some data, run a query like this [including the query dimension]".

I have two questions:

1. Is there any way around this limit? I need to use the 'query dimensions' but I'm wondering if I there are any ways to break it up into small chunks. I've tried requesting fewer rows at a time but still can't get anything past to 5000
2. Is there anywhere in the documentation that says 5,000 is the limit available per day if using the 'query' dimension?

Thanks in advance!